# Server Storing Variables For Each Client

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I have recently began working with multiplayer games in Unity. I am not using Photon Unity Networking but rather the built in networking inside Unity.

In the game I am trying to create, each player has their own money, and inventory variables. My original plan was to store these variable client-side, but I realized this was a bad idea.

What would be the best way to store these variable like money and inventory on the server? I tried making a "Player" class on the server, and created an instance of the class for every player that connected. However, after days of research and experiments, I was unable to find a way to do so successfully.

I'm sure this is a common concept for multiplayer games. So I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The way we choose to do it, was to create a very basic webservice (REST) which the server (and the server only) could talk to.

The webservice was written in Perl with MongoDB as storage backend, but the options here are almost endless, so use whatever you think is best for you.

Comment: I apologize. My question may be unclear. I was referring to having the server store variables for clients live while the client is connected. For example, lets say a player has $500 in game. If the client wanted to make a purchase, instead of simply subtracting the money value and adding an item to the player's inventory, instead I want the client to send an RPC to the server specifying what the player wanted to buy. The money will be subtracted, and the item will be added to a list stored on the server. This way there will be no way to "spawn" items simply by modifying the player's client.

Comment: I stand by my answer. :) I understand you want to have an authoritative server or some sort, and a backend REST service is perfect for this. The client tells the server "this player wants to buy this", the server then checks if it's OK, and it if is updates the player's money and inventory. The server and client then synchronizes the player's inventory and money values.